# "Reflected added to self" - word for it?

Tags: terminology

```
x += x[::-1]
```

I thought "reflect-superposed", or "reflect-added" ... any formal term for this? e.g. with linear chirp:

[image]

Comment: Which coding language is this expression written in?

Comment: @uriyaba Python; if `x=[1, 2, 3]`, then `x[::-1]=[3, 2, 1]`

Comment: Since this operation is not causal, i have not deal with any definition or terminology for describing this operation when applying it to time domain signals. Since the formula is $x(t)+x(\tau-t)$, you are tied to a parameter and things start to mess ("Tau reflect added"). Just my appreciation.